# Base table or view not found on Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a brand new installation on magento and manually installed the following plugin:

https://github.com/Instapago/magento-extension

when getting to its settings the following error appears:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'columpio_ssnickco_dbname086.instapago_instapagomodulo_instapago' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `instapago_instapagomodulo_instapago` AS `main_table`

 /home2/columpio/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
 /home2/columpio/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
 /home2/columpio/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
 /home2/columpio/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
 /home2/columpio/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
 /home2/columpio/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
 /home2/columpio/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(516): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(563): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(5): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/local/Instapago/InstapagoModulo/Block/Adminhtml/Instapago/Grid.php(48): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Instapago_InstapagoModulo_Block_Adminhtml_Instapago_Grid->_prepareCollection()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home2/columpio...')
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home2/columpio...')
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/local/Instapago/InstapagoModulo/controllers/Adminhtml/Instapagomodulo/InstapagoController.php(50): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Instapago_InstapagoModulo_Adminhtml_Instapagomodulo_InstapagoController->indexAction()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
 /home2/columpio/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 /home2/columpio/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
 {main}
```

I get that 'instapago_instapagomodulo_instapago' its initiated on: /app/code/local/Instapago/InstapagoModulo/etc/config.xml

I rebuild the indexes, and I'm stuck because I'm kind of new to magento so I dont really know what the error means.

Comment: I think module not installed correctly. This error is for instapago_instapagomodulo_instapago not found in db that is required by extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to run the applyUpdates.php script?

```
php shell/applyUpdates.php clearCache
```

Comment: Worked... I feel soo newbie, probably the lack of coffee. Thanks